# Reading a Specific Row of a CSV File based on the 1st Occurrence of a value within a Colum

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Below is the CSV File that I have:

```
Record  Time Value 1 Value 2 Value 3
Event   1    20      35      40
Event   2    48      43      56
Event   3    45      58      90
FFC     4    12      89      94
FFC     5    30      25      60
Event   6    99      45      13
```

I would like to use pandas in order to parse through the 'Record' Column until I find the first FFC and then print that entire row.  Additionally, I would like to print the row that is two above the first found FFC.  Any suggestions on how to approach this?

My reasoning for wanting to use Pandas is that I am going to need to call upon specific values within the two printed rows and plot them.

To start I have:

```
csvfile = pd.read_csv('Test.csv')
print(csvfile)
```

Thank you very much for your assistance, it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""Record  Time Value1 Value2 Value3
Event   1    20      35      40
Event   2    48      43      56
Event   3    45      58      90
FFC     4    12      89      94
FFC     5    30      25      60
Event   6    99      45      13""")

# replace mystr with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(mystr, delim_whitespace=True)

# get index of condition
idx = df[df['Record'] == 'FFC'].index[0]

# filter for appropriate indices
res1 = df.loc[idx]
res2 = df.loc[idx-2]
```

To output a dataframe:

```
print(res1.to_frame().T)

#   Record Time Value1 Value2 Value3
# 3    FFC    4     12     89     94
```

Comment: So this was what I got as an output: Record     FFC
Time         4
Value 1     12
Value 2     89
Value 3     94
Name: 4, dtype: object.........Is there a way to just print it in the same format (i.e. all the data from the row is printed on 1 line?  Additionally, how would I call upon for example the Time value (4) and the Value 1 (12) and plot that point on a graph?  Thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: Try `res1.to_frame().T`

Comment: I am still getting the same output format, any other work around?  Any idea on the plotting portion?

Comment: No, but try running my update *exactly as provided*.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much!  So is there a way to call out the values of 'Value 1' and 'Value 2' when the FFC Record occurs?

Comment: Yep. I'd advise you read up on it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

Comment: So, I tried using the following code but it isn't outputting the value of Value1 when the FFC occurs?  Can you please advise? value1 = res1.loc[0:2]

Comment: @bigballerbrand, please ask a separate question if you're still stuck.